# Working with threads with DCOM

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freeze, dcom, delphi-6

I have a conceptual question about multithreading:

In a application using RPC through DCOM, with multithread appartment configuration, the main form is freezing.

1 - If the CriticalSession is created in the unit initialization, the code in the critical session will run in the main thread context?

2 - When you call the method to execute a task:
      Thread 1 is created. (DCOM Thread) 
      Thread 1 creates Thread 2.
      Thread 1 WaitFor Thread 2.
      Thread 2 creates 4 thread to run the task faster.
      Thread 2 loops sleeping 2 seconds until the end of the 4 threads. In this processes the main form is supposed to be refreshed to display the percent done. A message is posted to the main form thread with the percent done, but nothing happens and the main form is freezed.

3 - There is a better way instead of synchronized() method, to synchronize inside one of the 4 threads when they need to CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) objects in the Thread 2?

4 - The 4 Threads have higher priority then the main thread is this a problem? When this become a problem?

The image below represent the architecture of the system:

[image: System Architecture]

Comment: This is a nitpick but I'd recommend changing the tags around a bit, maybe something like DCOM then multithreading, then the rest might not really be necessary since DCOM is (in theory) not effected by what language the client and server are using. If this is something specific to delphi, could you add more information about that? Or was this just a "here's the language I'm using in case it makes a difference" sort of thing?

Comment: @jrh  this just a "here's the language I'm using in case it makes a difference" sort of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: No. By using a cricital section, you guarantee the code is run in **only one** thread at a time; in practice any thread that calls Enter will *hang* there until any other thread that is also running that code gets to the Leave call. But this doesn't mean it will run in the main thread (check with GetCurrentThreadID)

2: You mention apartment configuration, but which apartment threading model? This defines when (D)COM will **do thread synchronzation for you**. In practice COM will work with proxy stubs and marshalling behind the scenes to *traverse* apartment (and network) boundaries, unless you've selected multi threaded apartment, in which case COM will suppose the components take care of threading issues by themselves.

If I understand correctly, the main form freezes on the 'Thread 1 WaitFor Thread 2'. Instead of calling WaitFor you'll be better off using the OnTerminate event on Thread2.

3: I'm not sure what you mean by 'CRUD objects in Thread 2'. If it is not important to know in what order the 4 threads finish, I would suggest to call WaitFor on the threads in sequence. If it is, you should check out [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

4: Different priorities should not be a problem. It only might be a problem when there are too much high-priority threads doing too much work so the normal-priority threads doing internal communication can't keep up, but in that case you should review how worker threads report their work.

Comment: it's better explained now?? Crud = (create read update and delete) and it is MultiThread Apartment.

Comment: as in database access? The 4 threads will need a database connection each or you'll get no performance enhancement, depending on which database you're using. My answer still stands.

Comment: Not database, haha... Access to memory objects, i just used the acronym to make it easy to type...

Comment: see if the image helps to understand

Comment: Can you give more information or a source for what sorts of thread synchronization that DCOM does, and when it uses it? (e.g., which thread do DCOM events come on? If the server has multiple threads raising events does the DCOM client just see them on a single thread?). I was looking for this information in [Inside COM (Dale Rogerson)](http://a.co/4mZzqkI) but he didn't cover it much. If it makes a difference I'm interested in local procedure calls (DCOM servers hosted in EXEs with the client and server on the same machine)

Comment: If I recall correctly, COM EXE's running locally (thus plain COM, not DCOM) actually create and export a hidden HWND that the ActiveX sub-system posts messages to with marshalled interface-call-data. Thus 'events' are run in the main thread that handles the message pump.

Comment: Interesting. Though note that in my case I think it really is DCOM, the EXE hosted server is DCOM *in case a client connects remotely*, though in my case the client isn't remote. Unless COM is smart enough to detect that it's connecting over localhost and degrade it to regular COM?

Comment: I think I might have gotten mixed up, a [service hosted DCOM component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809975.aspx) might not be the same thing as an exe hosted DCOM component

Comment: I stand corrected, it seems [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Procedure_Call) that modern Windows versions use a thing called ALPC under the hood...